# How to comply with the new Federal Desktop Core Configuration (FDCC), which will remove local administrator access for all users?

Tags: project-management, system-administration, administration

As developers, we believe that not having local administrative access is going to severely handicap our productivity.  We will be restricted from running IIS (we’re a web development shop), installing applications, running Microsoft power tools, etc.  If you’re going through the FDCC process now, it would be great to hear how you are coping with these changes.

Answer (score 10):

Having actively worked as a contract developer at a base that uses the AF Standard Desktop, I can tell you a few things.

1: and most important.  Don't fight it and don't do what the first person suggested "and let them choke on it".  That is absolutely the wrong attitude.  The military/government is fighting lack of funding, overstretched resources and a blossoming technology footprint that they don't understand.  The steps they are taking may not be perfect, but they are under attack and we need to be helping, not hindering.

OK, that off my chest.

2: You need to look at creating (and I know this is hard with funding the way it is) a local development lab.  Every base that I have worked at has an isolated network segement that you can get on that has external access, that is isolated from the main gov network.  You basically have your work PC for e-mail, reports etc.. that is on the protected network. But, you develop in your small lab.  I've had a lab be 2 PCs tucked under my desk that were going to be returned during a tech refresh.  In other words, be creative with making yourself a development machine +servers that are NOT restricted.  Those machines are just not allowed to be connected to the main lan segment.

3: Get the distributions of the desktop configurations.  Part of your testing needs to be deploying/running on these configurations.  Again, these configurations are not meant for development boxes.  They are meant to be the machines the people use for day to day gov work.

4: If you are working on web solutions, be very aware of the restrictions on adding trusted sites, ActiveX components, certs, certain types of script execution that the configuration won't allow.  Especially if you are trying to embed widgets/portlets/utils that require communications outside the deployed application domain.

5: Above all remember that very few of the people you work for understand the technology they are asking you to implement.  They know they want function X but they want you to follow draconian security rule Y while achieving it.  What that usually means is that the "grab some open source lib or plugin and go" is not an option.  But, that is exactly what your managers think you are going to do because of the buzz around rapid development.

In summary, it's a mess out there.  Try to help solve the problem.

Comment: Having lived with an overly burdened development environment myself, I wish more people had taken this advice!

Answer (score 6):

While I've never been through the FDCC process, I once worked for a U.S. defense contractor who's policy was that no one had local administrative access to their machines. In addition, flash drives and CD-ROMs were disabled (if you wanted to listen to music on CDs, you had to have a personal CD player with headphones).

If you needed software installed you had to put in a work order. Someone would show up at your desk with the install media, login to a local admin account, and let you install the software (the reasoning being that you knew what to install better than they did). Surprisingly, the turnaround was pretty quick, usually around 1/2 an hour.

While an inconvenience, this policy didn't really cripple us. We were doing a combination of Java, C++ (MS Visual C++ and GNU/C++), VB 6.0 and some web development. For what little web development we did, we had a remote dev box we would RDP into for testing. Again, a bit of an inconvenience, but it didn't stop us from getting our jobs done.

Answer (score 2):

Without ever having had the problem, today I'd probably try a virtualising solution to run these tools.

Or, as a friend of mine once opined: "Follow the process until They choke on it." In this case this'd probably mean calling the helpdesk each time you needed to have a modification to your local IIS config or you'd needed one of the powertools started.

Comment: My company (in Germany) wanted to do something similar, e.g. no unauthorized software on the machines, and such. They folded pretty quickly after I handed them the first 200 request forms for the > 1000 installed packages on my Linux box. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite common within financial institutions. I personally treat this as a game to see how much software I can run on my PC without any admin rights or sending requests to the support group.

So far I have done pretty well I have only sent one software install request which was for "Rational Software Architect" ('cos I need the plugins from the "official" release). Apart from that I have perl, php, python, apache  all up and running. In addition I have jetty server, maven, winscp, putty, vim and a several other tools running quite happlily on my desktop.

So it shouldnt really bother you that much, and, even though I am one of the worst offenders when it comes to installing unofficial software I would recommend "no admin rights" to any shop remotly interested in securing their applications and networks.

One common practice is to give developers an "official" locked down PC on which they can run the official applications and do their eMail admin etc. and a bare bones development workstation to which they have admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell FDCC is only intended to be a recommended security baseline.  I'd give some push back on the privileges that you require and see what they can come up with to accommodate your request.  Instead of saying I need to be a local administrator, I'd list the things that you need to be able to do and let them come up with a solution that works (which will likely to be to let you administer your machine or a VM).  You need to be able to run the debugger in Visual Studio, run a local web server (Cassini), install patches/updates to your dev tools on your schedule, ...

I recently moved to a "semi-managed" environment with SCCM that gets patches installed on a regular basis from a local update repository.  I was doing this myself, but this is marginally more efficient for the enterprise and it makes the security office happy.  I did get them to put me, and the other developers, in a special collection so that we could block breaking changes if needed (how could IE7 be a security update?).  Not much broke except that now I need to update Windows Defender manually since I updated it more frequently than they do in the managed collection!  It wasn't as extreme as your case, obviously, but I think that is, in part, due to the fact that I was able to present the case for things that I needed to do for my job that required more local control.

From the NIST FAQ on Securing WinXP.

> 12. Should I make changes to the baseline settings? Given the wide
>       variation in operational and technical
>       considerations for operating any major
>       enterprise, it is appropriate that
>       some local changes will need to be
>       made to the baseline and the
>       associated settings (with hundreds of
>       settings, a myriad of applications,
>       and the variety of business functions
>       supported by Windows XP Systems, this
>       should be expected). Of course, use
>       caution and good judgment in making
>       changes to the security settings.
>       Always test the settings on a
>       carefully selected test machine first
>       and document the implemented settings.

Answer (score 1):

Not having local administrative access to your workstation is a pain in the rear for sure. I had to deal with that while I was working for my university as a web developer in one of the academic departments. Every time I needed something installed such as Visual Studio or Dreamweaver I had to make a request to Computing Services.